# What exceptions can be thrown by DataSet.ReadXml(string)

Tags: .net, xml, dataset

Does anybody know what types of exceptions can be thrown by the method "DataSet.ReadXml(string filename)"?

There only "SecurityException" specified in the MSDN. But I think that there is more possible exceptions that can be thrown from this method. Or maybe I'm wrong?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360dye2a.aspx) states, an InvalidOperationException will also be thrown if there is a problem parsing the Xml in the specified file.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is incomplete there. There might be also a XMLException thrown, which is a generic exception for XML namespace.